# Zend MVC - htaccess redirect

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite

All,
My Zend framework Application structure is like this:

```
billingsystem
 -application
 -design
    --css
        --struct.css
    --icons
    --styles
    --images
    --js
       --common
       --thirdparty
 -public
    --index.php
    --.htaccess
 -library
    -- Zend
```

My Apache VHost is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@billingsystem.localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/billingsystem
    ServerName billingsystem
    ErrorLog logs/billingsystem.localhost-error.log
    CustomLog logs/billingsystem.localhost-access.log common
    <directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/billingsystem>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess in public folder is like this:

```
RewriteEngine   on
# The leading %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} is necessary when used in VirtualHost context
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If I browse to http://billingsystem, it shows the apache directory path on the browser. If I go to http://billingsystem/public, the application executes code on the web page. Is it possible to create or modify .htaccess file such that, when a user browses to http://billingsystem, it should redirect the browser to http://billingsystem/public and execute the code instead of showing the directory structure?

Also, how can I redirect the user to "public" directory when he tries to access any folder through the browser?

Answer (score 3):

I just went through something like this on a site. My solution was that I needed to use two .htaccess files on the domain. One in the root level of the site and another in the `public` folder.

So, the one at the root of the domain looks like this:

```
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#Zend Rewrite Rules
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]

AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Within the `public` folder I have the following rules in place:

```
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This seems to work well to get all content trafficking through the Zend framework.

Hope this is helpful. 
- liam

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question you can place a `.htaccess` directly in the `billingsystem` folder with a rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]`

However, your setup should look more like the following:

**File System**

```
billingsystem
 -application
 -design
 -public
    --index.php
    --.htaccess
 -library
    -- Zend
```

**Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@billingsystem.localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/billingsystem/public
    ServerName billingsystem
    ErrorLog logs/billingsystem.localhost-error.log
    CustomLog logs/billingsystem.localhost-access.log common
    <directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/billingsystem/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now the question that remains is that i know you have stuff in you `design` directory that aparently needs to be web accessible... Can you elaborate on the directory structure in `design` so that we can figure out what you need to do (if anything) to properly access the various types of files contained in it?

Comment: Please see the directory structure edit in my post. Now, I tried to move design folder into public folder.. My header.phtml file in /application/view/scripts folder tries to access it using /design/css/struct.css.. It didn't work for me this way..

Comment: Did you remove the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` from the rewrite rules like in my example? Also what happens if you point your browser at `http://www.billingsystem/design/struct.css` what kind of error do you get?

Comment: Also you might want to use the `baseUrl()` function to generate that css path as well if youre currently hard coding it.

Comment: Yes..I removed the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} as you suggested. When I browse to that css like you suggested, it redirects me to a custom error controller telling page not found..

Comment: Ok easy stuff first - You did restart Apache after modifying the VirtualHost correct? Are owner, group and their respective permissions for `/design/css/struct.css` **identical** to those for `/index.php`? How are you including the stylsheet and what is the code you are using (ie. are you using the `headLink` helper, hard coding the entire tag, echoing an `@import` directive, etc..)?

Comment: +1 because it was helpful for me even though it may not solve the problem posed in the question.